# "Debut video capture" directly encoding to webm?

Tags: windows-7, video-encoding

I've bought [Debug Video Capture](http://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/index.html) and I've quite some codecs to choose from for encoding (.e.g h264, mpeg4, etc.). System is W7 Pro x64.

However I'm missing webm badly. I know I can just use ffmpeg or similar to transcode it in a second step, but I'd like to save that and just have everything encoded to webm by default.

From my understanding, Debut Video Captures uses existing Windows 7 infrastructure for encoding videos; I take this from their knowledge base entry: [Encoder Options for AVI Files](http://www.nch.com.au/kb/10068.html)

I installed [WebM Video for Microsoft Internet Explorer 9](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/webmmf) (which is installed as *Webm Media Foundation*) but it probably is only for playback, it didn't add any webm encoding options to Debut.

If my assumption about Debut is true, I "only" need to find a suitable webm installer package which provides native webm encoding to Windows 7.

Now that I read the knowledge base entry again, it says "Encode Options for AVI Files". Bummer, I guess, because I know that webm is container and vp8 is the codec, etc.

But maybe I'm lucky and someone has an idea?

Comment: Maybe [here](http://www.webmproject.org/tools/#directshow-filters)? Don't have Windows, so I can't try whether Debut actually uses all available installed codecs. Maybe you can ask the developers if you've bought their software?

Comment: @slhck: ah, I think this is what I've been searching for. I installed it and the references codecs from xiph.org; I get to select the codec but the software errors out "Cannot show video preview". Unfortunately no more specifics are given. There's no way to contact the developers besides paying for a support plan, not something I'm considering. They've set up a forum at http://nch.invisionzone.com/index.php?showforum=54 but there's nothing related found so I didn't even try there (yet...)

Comment: Actually, from the help menu in Debut, you can choose to make a suggestion to the developers.  Tell them to add support for the WebM codec.

Comment: @BonGart: nice suggestion, did that immediately, thanks. There's one thing I don't get about this company NHC: their products seem to be really good but they're shy as mice when it comes to open up communications channels for their community (next time I will simply ignore such products when there's doubt they're more open ...)

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is to use the "Run external application" feature, it can be found under
**File ➮ Options ➮ Output ➮ Run external application**:

When activated, you can run an arbitrary application to do whatever you want with you video file. I use it now with a `.bat` file which calls `ffmpeg` with some options to produce the `.webm` file.